# @PostConstruct @PreDestroy

Tags: java, deprecated, java-9

In *jdk9* `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` are in `java.xml.ws.annotation` which is deprecated and scheduled for removal.

I was wondering what to use when they are removed and also wouldn't be a problem due to the fact that a lot of frameworks and projects are using them?

Comment: Hi, this is a good topic for a forum, it doesn't fit that well here

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a duplicate existing for this. Ideally, move to use `<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: These annotations annotations are in

 - Module `java.xml.ws.annotation` 
 - Package `javax.annotation`

The module has been deprecated in [JEP-320][1], and the annotations have been published as standalone (Maven) artefact: [javax annotation API][2]

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


  [1]: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320
  [2]: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:javax.annotation%20AND%20a:javax.annotation-api

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer on [this link](https://better-coding.com/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-alternatives-in-java-9/)

This example is just first example which should prepare your code for the latest modifications:

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private void init() {
        //TODO: init code
    }


    private void shutdown() {
        //TODO: destroy code
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just a  Spring way of doing this?

Comment: @nullpointer Yeah, the class should be managed by Spring.

Comment: @DannyPopow then you have your solution there in the link, I would still prefer the one without the code implementation change.